# Service Registry Issue in Eureka Server

Tags: rest, spring-boot, docker-compose, restful-architecture, dock

I'm facing issue with Spring Boot Registry with Eureka Server. The discovery service is registered and the other one is not registered.

My application.yml for discovery as below,

```
spring:
  application:
    name: swimming-pool-discovery-client
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
```

The registration service application.yml as below.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: swimming-pool-reservation-service
server:
  port: 8181
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
```

Discovery pom.xml as below,

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Dalston.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <artifactId>discovery-service</artifactId>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <docker.image.prefix>swimming-pool</docker.image.prefix>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.13</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                    <dockerDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

My registration pom.xml as below,

```
<properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <docker.image.prefix>swimming-pool</docker.image.prefix>
    </properties>
    <artifactId>reservation-service</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.13</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                    <dockerDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Java Classes are,

```
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class DisoveryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DisoveryApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableEurekaClient
public class ReservationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReservationApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The below exception am facing,

```
reservation-service_1  | 2018-04-17 14:26:36.428  WARN 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
reservation-service_1  | 2018-04-17 14:26:36.429  WARN 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_SWIMMING-POOL-RESERVATION-SERVICE/d34463b43007:swimming-pool-reservation-service:8181 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server
reservation-service_1  |
reservation-service_1  | com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
reservation-service_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
reservation-service_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
reservation-service_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
reservation-service_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
reservation-service_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
reservation-service_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:798) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
reservation-service_1  |        at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:104) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
reservation-service_1  |        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_111]
reservation-service_1  |        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_111]
reservation-service_1  |        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_111]
reservation-service_1  |        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_111]
reservation-service_1  |        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
reservation-service_1  |        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
reservation-service_1  |        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
reservation-service_1  |
reservation-service_1  | 2018-04-17 14:26:36.430  WARN 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : There was a problem with the instance info replicator
```

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration of your discovery service is not correct. Change your `application.yml` to be like this

```
spring:
  application:
    name: swimming-pool-discovery-client
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
```

Your configuration for registration service is correct. But you don't need `@EnableDiscoveryClient` and 
`@EnableEurekaClient`
 both. Just use `@EnableEurekaClient`

Comment: Thank you very much Kiran, I tried above suggestion but no luck, instead am getting the below error.
EMERGENCY! EUREKA MAY BE INCORRECTLY CLAIMING INSTANCES ARE UP WHEN THEY'RE NOT. RENEWALS ARE LESSER THAN THRESHOLD AND HENCE THE INSTANCES ARE NOT BEING EXPIRED JUST TO BE SAFE."

Comment: When i run stand alone it works fine and putting all together in docker, issue.

Comment: then there might be some issue with port setting when u run docker